# Permanently remove class with jquery and override other code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a website that has some default jquery set up that I am trying to override. It's big and complicated so I will try and explain this as simply as possible.

I have a div called "dropdown-container", and within this div is an anchor link with a dropdown. have removed all the default jquery classes on the dropdown container (such as "ui-state-hover", etc). When the page loads this works fine - all those default jquery classes are removed. However as soon as I click on the anchor tag within the div, the classes get added back onto my "dropdown-container" which messes up what I'm trying to achieve.

Is there a way to ensure these classes never get added back onto my "dropdown-container", no matter what?

Here is my jquery code:

```
    function mobileMainNav(){

        jQuery(".footer-menu-accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: ".level2-featured, .level3-featured, .level4-featured, .level4",
            autoHeight:false
        });

        $('.dropdown-container').removeClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-state-active ui-corner-top");

        $('.dropdown-container').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropogation();
            $('.dropdown-container').removeClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-state-active ui-corner-top");    
        })

        $('a.level-1.direct').click(function(e){
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        }); 

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either hide the entire dropdown-container, then have your own dropdown which maps values between controls. That way you don't have to worry about the dropdown reformatting.

Another option is to wrap a timer event which is constantly polling for a class to reappear, then remove it. YMMV for user experience on that one.

e.g.

```
function clearClass() {
  $(".ui-accordion-header").removeClass(".ui-accordion-header");
}
setInterval(clearClass, 1000);
```

Finally, you could remove the top-level dropdown-container (and maybe give it a class dropdown-container2) and update necessary styles. I assume the ui library is checking for the dropdown-container class.

Comment: the dropdown container is my own class, it is within a parent element that adds the ui classes to whatever is inside. i need to keep the ui classes for my menu to work, just on this specific div i need them to not be added.